# Android Canvas.DrawBitmap without blurring/AntiAliasing?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to make an android game using sprites, (or very pixelated characters, backgrounds etc.). I draw them on the canvas like so...

`matrix.preScale(xrat,yrat);`

`canvas.drawBitmap(img, matrix, null);`

Where img is the Bitmap and the xrat and yrat are the scales.

My problem is that when I test, the Bitmap is blurry or anti-aliased, is there a way to prevent this? The rigid-blocky art style of the game will be ruined if the blocks are blurry.

Any (ANY) help appreciated!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Create a new Paint to use when drawing the bitmaps with the settings:

```
Paint drawPaint = new Paint();
drawPaint.setAntiAlias(false);
drawPaint.setFilterBitmap(false);
```

Filtering I believe is on by default and will attempt to smooth out bitmaps when drawn scaled up.

Comment: I believe filtering is only applied if you are scaling UP, not DOWN.  Just wanted to point this out since the OP did not specify.

Comment: Hey thanks guys soooo much, I would also like to add to anyone who is making a 8-bit game or trying to do what I'm doing, you need to put your image resources in drawable-hdpi or android will filter it anyway.